# Automatically calculate normals in GLKit/OpenGL-ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios5, geometry, glkit

I'm making some fairly basic shapes in OpenGL-ES based on sample code from Apple. They've used an array of points, with an array of indices into the first array and each set of three indices creates a polygon. That's all great, I can make the shapes I want. To shade the shapes correctly I believe I need to calculate normals for each vertex on each polygon. At first the shapes were cuboidal so it was very easy, but now I'm making (slightly) more advanced shapes I want to create those normals automatically. It seems easy enough if I get vectors for two edges of a polygon (all polys are triangles here) and use their cross product for every vertex on that polygon. After that I use code like below to draw the shape.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleVertices);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleColours);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, triangleNormals);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 48);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is why I have to do this manually. I'm sure there are cases when you'd want something other than just a vector perpendicular to the surface, but I'm also sure that this is the most popular use case by far, so shouldn't there be an easier way? Have I missed something obvious? glCalculateNormals() would be great.

//And here is an answer
Pass in a GLKVector3[] that you wish to be filled with your normals, another with the vertices (each three are grouped into polygons) and then the count of the vertices.

```
- (void) calculateSurfaceNormals: (GLKVector3 *) normals forVertices: (GLKVector3 *)incomingVertices count:(int) numOfVertices
{

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfVertices; i+=3)
    {
        GLKVector3 vector1 = GLKVector3Subtract(incomingVertices[i+1],incomingVertices[i]);
        GLKVector3 vector2 = GLKVector3Subtract(incomingVertices[i+2],incomingVertices[i]);        
        GLKVector3 normal = GLKVector3Normalize(GLKVector3CrossProduct(vector1, vector2));
        normals[i] = normal;
        normals[i+1] = normal;
        normals[i+2] = normal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And again the answer is: **OpenGL is neither a scene managment library nor a geometry library, but just a drawing API** that draws nice pictures to the screen. For lighting it needs normals and you give it the normals. That's all. Why should it compute normals if this can just be done by the user and has nothing to do with the actual drawing?

Often you don't compute them at runtime anyway, but load them from a file. And there are many many ways to compute normals. Do you want per-face normals or per-vertex normals? Do you need any specific hard edges or any specific smooth patches? If you want to average face normals to get vertex normals, how do you want to average these?

And with the advent of shaders and the removing of the builtin normal attribute and lighting computations in newer OpenGL versions, this whole question becomes obsolete anyway as you can do lighting any way you want and don't neccessarily need traditional normals anymore.

By the way, it sounds like at the moment you are using per-face normals, which means every vertex of a face has the same normal. This creates a very faceted model with hard edges and also doesn't work very well together with indices. If you want a smooth model (I don't know, maybe you really want a faceted look), you should average the face normals of the adjacent faces for each vertex to compute per-vertex normals. That would actually be the more usual use-case and not per-face normals.

So you can do something like this pseudo-code:

```
for each vertex normal:
    intialize to zero vector

for each face:
    compute face normal using cross product
    add face normal to each vertex normal of this face

for each vertex normal:
    normalize
```

to generate smooth per-vertex normals. Even in actual code this should result in something between 10 and 20 lines of code, which isn't really complex.

Comment: I had have thought my case was the majority case, but if it's not how it's usually done then I can understand it being a manual job. I do mostly want blocks so I'll probably stick with my system. With the averaged averaged vertex normal method you describe how do I tell OpenGL that though I have 12 polygons and 36 vertices that I've only calculated 8 normals? Do I need an array of 36 normals to match the vertices and I place the normals in the same order? This would mean some get repeated when ever two polygons share a vertex, or is there a way to link normal and vertex?

Comment: @Craig You always have one normal for each vertex. If you compute normals your way (per-face) each face normal has to be repeated for each vertex of a face. If you compute per-vertex normals, each vertex normal is repeated for each face a vertex is part of, like the vertices actually. Conceptually a vertex is the entirety of all its attributes and not just the position, which is unfortunately called vertex, too, in OpenGL.

Comment: @Craig But the advantage of per-vertex normals (regarding storage efficiency) is, that you can use an index array (and `glDrawElements`) and reduce the duplication entirely, because each unique vertex has the same normal. With per-face normals, indices won't buy you anything, because you need to duplicate vertices anyway, as each vertex with a unique position may have more than one different normal.

Comment: @Craig So basically what you said is the way to do it, since if you have 36 vertices you also have 36 vertex normals and not just 8. How could it be 8, you don't even know beforehand taht you only have 8 unique normals, since you, well, didn't yet compute any. So yes the normal array (and every other attribute array) always matches the vertex array, no matter which values it contains.

Comment: The 8 normals were for a cube, where there are 8 vertices and an index array. Within that index array it would be something like {0,1,2,  0,2,3) saying which vertexes to use for each polygon, three at a time. I'd then use that same index array to order (and repeat) the eight normals, one for each vertex on each polygon. That's if I wanted them averaged, which I don't. the cross product suits my blocks pretty well. Thanks

Comment: @Craig Yes, and if you don't want per-vertex normals averaged, you don't have 8 vertices but 24, since you have to repeat the face normal for each vertex of a cube face. But in this case you can also just drop the index array completely and use `glDrawArrays`. In this case you of course need 36 vertices. The point is, always keep in mind that a vertex is not just a position, but all of a vertex' attributes together. So duplication is natural if you want two vertices have the same position but different normals, which is needed when using per-face normals.